# Routing IP over WiFi bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-bridge

I am thinking of buying a smart IP-based video intercom with 5 clients (it is basically a computer with video-over-IP marketed as an intercom).

I dont want to dig the whole property and pay to lay the ethernet cables underground with PoE switch on one side. I am thinking of connecting one wire into a WiFi bridge and installing second bridge on the building and then connect clients to it.

I dont see why it wont work, but given high cost of the system I am reluctant to buy it just to try.

Any ideas why it might **not** work?

Comment: I can't think of any. Sufficiently powerful directional antennas, proper protection against the elements and a direct, clear line-of-sight; and you should be good. This kind of wireless bridging is used all over in places where digging cables is inconvenient or unviable, and carry signal over kilometers when done right.

Comment: Yeah I think so too.. But am more concerned abt networking per se. What if central unit won't find the clients if connected over a bridge. What if there are several flavours of bridges (on transport level) where one might work and others won't..

Comment: The key concept is "done right". On purely networking point of view (i.e. transport level) it's all just data paths. Devices don't care whether the bits are carried by modulating voltage, light or radio signal, as long as the signal flows. Distances and interference do matter, as does the choice of hardware. There aren't really too many flavours of solutions, as they all use the same radio technology anyway. Consumer devices mightn't cut it, but devices that don't work disappear pretty fast from pro market. The safest way is to let a professional do the installation. At least it's a good idea

Comment: to consult one. Giving advice on a forum like this isn't really easy as space and available info is limited. But in general terms what you're thinking about is nothing really special. With this data I'd say 2 quality APs with good, directional outdoor antennas, one managed switch, one ISP router and some cable and it's done. Add a few wallmount RJ45 boxes and cable runners, and it's done neat. Or just powerline adapters. It's really just a question of what d'ya want to achieve with what budget. The bridge isn't really a big deal anymore; we communicate wirelessly all the time :-)

Comment: Just write that a bridge is completely transparent and agnostic to networks it connect as an answer and I'll mark it. Thank you.. PS I am looking at tp-link CPE with PTMP capability as I will need to bridge 3 points.